# Jupyter notebook cannot connect to Python kernel

Tags: python, azure, jupyter-notebook

Just created a Jupyter notebook on https://notebooks.azure.com for trying it out.
When opening it, it seems the notebook cannot connect to the kernel (Python 3.6). I get the error:
"A connection to the notebook server could not be established. The notebook will continue trying to reconnect. Check your network connection or notebook server configuration."

When opening the browser (Chrome) console it says something like:
"WebSocket connection failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Incorrect 'Sec-WebSocket-Accept' header value"

Any clues as to what this could be all about?

Comment: Hi I work on Azure Notebooks.

If you wouldn't mind sharing your username on Azure Notebooks with me, and the time of this error, I can see if we can't figure out what went wrong for you. You can also always open an issue on our GitHub https://github.com/Microsoft/AzureNotebooks.

Also, I assume this isn't continuing to happen?

Thanks!

Comment: @ChristopherWilcox: thanks for you comment! I tried it out at home yesterday evening and it worked just fine. Here at work it does not. So I assume this is some sort of network config issue here at work.. I am reluctant to analyse it further at the moment, though, will simply work from a different network for now.. thanks anyway!